# Grab an image via the web and save it with Python

Tags: python, image

I want to be able to download an image (to my computer or to a web server) resize it, and upload it to S3. The piece concerned here is:

What would be a recommended way to do the downloading portion within Python (i.e., don't want to use external tools, bash, etc). I want it to be stored into memory until it's done with (versus downloading the image to a local drive, and then working with it). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) (simple but a bit rough) and [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (powerful but a bit more complicated) are the recommended standard library modules for grabbing data from a URL (either to memory or to disk).  For simple-enough needs, `x=urllib.urlopen(theurl)` will give you an object that lets you access the response headers (e.g. to find out the image's content-type) and data (as `x.read()`); `urllib2` works similarly but lets you control proxying, user agent, coockies, https, authentication, etc, etc, much more than simple `urllib` does.

Answer (score 1):

[Pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/), [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), and [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) are all options. Pycurl is a Python interface for libcurl, and urllib and urllib2 are both part of Python's standard library. urllib is simple, urllib2 is more powerful but also more complicated.

urllib example:

```
import urllib
image = urllib.URLopener()
image.urlretrieve("http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png")
```

In this case, the file is not stored in local memory, but rather as a temp file with a generated name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen(url_of_image)
image = f.read()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0):

<del>You could always have a look at [hand](http://code.google.com/p/hand/).</del>

<del>If I remember correctly, it was written to grab cartoons from sites that don't have feeds</del>

This project seems to have died, so it's no longer an option. Anyway, using `urllib` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks @monkey for letting me know the link was not working. I edited the answer since the project seems to be dead now.