# Python -- how to grab images off the internet

Tags: python, image, download

How can I grab a picture off of a known url and save it to my computer using Python (v2.6)? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482600/grab-an-image-via-the-web-and-save-it-with-python

Comment: Kai -- that one doesn't want to save it to the local drive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve).

> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary.

Example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlretrieve('http://i.imgur.com/Ph4Xw.jpg', 'duck.jpg')
('duck.jpg', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x10118e830>)
# by now the file should be downloaded to 'duck.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://example.com/file.png', './file.png')
```

If you need more flexibility, use `urllib2`.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any context, the following is a simple example of using standard library modules to make an non-authenticated HTTP GET request

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1674.jpg')
with open('lolcat.jpg', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(response.read())
```

**EDIT:** `urlretrieve()` is new to me. I guess then you *could* turn it into a command line one-liner... if you're bored.

```
$ python -c "import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve('http://lolcat.com/images/lolcats/1674.jpg', filename='/tmp/1674.jpg')"
```

Comment: How does one make an authenticated request? And does it make a difference as to which one you go for?

Answer (score 0):

batteries are included in [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

`urllib.urlretrieve(yourUrl, fileName)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2
open("fish.jpg", "w").write(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.fiskeri.no/Fiskeslag/Fjesing.jpg").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.dokuwiki.org/_media/wiki:dokuwiki-128.png","dafile.png")
```